# OpenId with Desktop Application?

Tags: openid

We're using an API from a provider; in their next version, they would provide an OpenId server but mostly the users are using their desktop application. An other website we're building would be opened from this application and we supposedly would connect with openid to access the resources stored in this provider.

Still I don't understand how this would work if user is already authenticated with the desktop, will they have to authenticate an other time ? What happens if they close their browser and reopen it, will they have to to do it again ?

Answer (score 5):

OpenID and desktop apps are totally completely and altogether incompatible.  You cannot secure a desktop app using OpenID.

Look at OAuth.  It can work with or without OpenID, but OAuth is all about authorizing apps including desktop apps to access network resources.

Comment: In what sense is it not secure?

Comment: Alex, it's like locking up your car and asking how you didn't secure your house.  You have to ask yourself what you're actually protecting.  A desktop app is entirely vulnerable (as one example) to a local user spoofing the communication with the OpenID Provider, which would enable him/her to masquerade as any other user.  Also, OpenID does not empower the desktop app to "prove" the identity of the local user to any remote network resource, so neither local nor network resources can be protected by OpenID for desktop apps.

Comment: @ Andrew, Google openID returns a unique guid instead of the account name to the openID relayer. Since there is no way to guess what this guid is, it would be impossible to impersonate a user, no? If a desktop app were to limit itself to only accept openID providers that return a guid instead of the openid account, would the application be secure? I wish to use the guid as a secret key to encrypt local data.

Comment: Google doesn't use a GUID.  It uses what crypto-identity folks call a "pseudonymous identifier".  And while it's impossible to predict what the identifier will be for any given RP, it's not "secret".  And using another application (Google's) non-secret as a cryptographic key sounds like you're setting your users up for poor security.  Windows (and I hope other OSs) already have built-in, easily accessible means for encrypting per-user data such that only that user can read it.  Have you considered that?

Comment: To people reading this answer: Make sure to remember the difference between Authentication and Authorization. OAuth only provide authorization, not authentication. Don't use OAuth to authenticate desktop app.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is "it depends."  For the close-and-reopened browser question, it depends on whether your sites use session cookies or persistent cookies to authenticate requests.

But as for the authenticate-with-desktop-client-and-then-open-a-browser, you'd have to ask the provider for more details.  I can imagine ways to do it that would have either outcome.